# MachineKey.Unprotect equivalent in php

Tags: c#, php, encryption

I am working with some C# developer in a team. They encrypted a cookie via c# and I am supposed to decrypt it and use it on another subdomain via php.
what they send me as c# code to decrypt it is:

```
    var cookie = Request.Cookies["mycookie"];

    if (cookie != null)
    {
         var key = "Hn9*e$";
         var bytes = Convert.FromBase64String(cookie.Value);
         var output = MachineKey.Unprotect(bytes, key);
         var result = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(output);
    }
```

I wonder how can I do this in PHP.
I know how to decode base64 but for the rest of that I have no idea and i could not find a clue.

Comment: I'm no expert, but it seems to me that you need the information in the machineKey configuration section in the web.config file for the C# app. Without it, you wouldn't know what encryption algorithm has been used, nor the key to decrypt the data.

Comment: I know the key as "Hn9*e$" which is mentioned in the code

Comment: As I said I'm no expert, but it seems from the MSDN documentation that the string passed to Unprotect is not the key, but rather an description of what the data is meant for. You still need the information from web.config.